# How do you build individual project artifacts in azure deveops pipeline

Tags: c#, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, asp.net-core-3.1

I have multiple projects contained in my repo that I would like to build individual zip artifact to deploy them each separately. Currently, the pipeline builds one zip artifact that contains all the projects. How do I configure my azure-pipelines.yml file to accomplish this task? Below is my current file.

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package 
/p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true 
/p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\WebApp.zip" 
/p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

Comment: Not getting your latest information... If the answer below is helpful, please mark it as answer, just click the option like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/515442). Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here and I'll try my best to help :)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you define the MSBuild arguments. The `/p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\WebApp.zip"  /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site"` is the direct cause of the issue, it  calls msbuild to package all projects into one `WebApp.zip` file.

With `msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)"'` you can have separate `ProjectName.zip` files under `$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)` path.

And then you can use one `Publish Build Artifact task` to publish whole `$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)` directory which contains `ProjectA.zip`, `ProjectB.zip`...

Also you can use several `Publish Build Artifact tasks` in one pipeline for your several output `xx.zip` files.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the build parameter `/p:PackageAsSingleFile=false` which will prevent all the projects from being zipped together. If you want to move the built files after the build, before the Publish Artifacts step, you can create a Copy files task that will copy the project's build folder to another location within the
'$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'

steps:

- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy Project Files'
  inputs:
  SourceFolder: '$\ProjectName\bin$(BuildConfiguration)'
  Contents: '****'
  TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\ProjectName'
  CleanTargetFolder: true

Though these will all still be placed within the 'drop' folder or whatever the $(build.artifactstagingdirectory) is called. The only way to separate artifacts is to create separate pipelines for each project.